# AP Computer Science: ArrayList Multiple Choice

Tags: arrays, methods, arraylist, java

Consider the following method hat is intended to modify its parameter `nameList` by replacing all occurrences of `name` with `newValue`

```
public void replace(ArrayList<String> nameList, String name, String newValue) {

    for (int j = 0; j < nameList.size(); j++) {

        if (/*expression*/)
            namelist.set(j, newValue);

    }
}
```

Which of the following can be used to replace /* expression */ so that `replace` will work as intended?

```
(a) nameList.get(j).equals(name)
(b) ...
(c) ...
(d) ...
(e) nameList[j].equals(name)
```

I chose `e`, but the correct answer is `a`. I don't quite understand why `a` works but not `e`, and I'm not entirely sure what the difference is between the two...

You can find the question here, on page 9:
http://xhs-java-oop.wikispaces.com/file/view/PracticeProblems.pdf

Comment: (e) would not compile because nameList is not an array type. But even with (a) the code would not compile because namelist.set(j, newValue) refers to namelist instead of nameList (nitpicking but i guess its an exam question)

Comment: @salyh looking at the original exam it appears that that was just a typo by the poster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are given an `ArrayList`, which does not function like a plain old array. An ArrayList gives the method `.get(int i)` to return the element at index `i`.

This is because an `ArrayList` is a class, with methods and fields, rather than a primitive data type.